# Standard cache in Glassfish 3

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm using Glassfish 3. I have a jax-rs service that produces some data I'd like to cache for 5 minutes so I don't have to constantly go fetch it.

Is there a standard cache that comes with Glassfish or I have to import one?

The only cache related doc I could find is only for resource caching: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beagm/index.html

Comment: Have you considered using a reverse proxy instead? An external cache may be the simplest and most effective solution in such case.

Comment: I meant I want to cache it on the glassfish server and not have to go back to the different sources to fetch it constantly. Something like an ehcache or something like that.